# HTML fluid (percentage widths) not scaling properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My HTML fluid site isn't scaling properly on iPhone 4/S/5 and iPad devices.  My minimum container div scale is set to 480px.  I do not see why it's not scaling properly.  Might it be  in my meta: initial-scale=1.0?

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CtPpg/2/

Comment: may be it can help resolve your problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152474/confused-on-initial-scale-1-0-iphone-3gs-vs-4

Comment: What do you mean by "not scaling properly"? What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you are setting a px width for your min-width? Correct me if I am wrong, but it should be a percentage value, to make it truly fluid.

Answer (score 1):

the max-device-width for ipads is 1024 whereas for iphones, its 480px. you may need to use media queries to address both the devices.

ipads : `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {`

iphones: `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {`

look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtPpg/6/)

changes:

```
 max-width: 480px; 
 /*max-width: 800px;  #### set your max width here #### */
```

Comment: shouldn't my fluid widths take care of this?  I also want this to be viewable on desktop browsers, so a minimun of 480 isn't great.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I have put together a blog http://silence-uncovered.blogspot.com/ , with whatever I learnt when I did an HTML email for desktops, mobiles etc, shouldn't be much different for websites. Basically, you would need to read/experiment a bunch :) ...good luck! could you pls accept my answer, helps me get some points.

Comment: to make it work on desktops as well you would probably need `width='100%' min-width='480px'`