# Disable Zoom on Website

Tags: mobile-safari, zooming, scale, viewport, pinchzoom

I wanted to disable zooming on my Webpage.
Therefor I used this:

```
 <meta name="viewport" 
       content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

This works just fine on my iPhone but when I try this with my LG Optimus 4x, I am still able to zoom!

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android viewport setting "user-scalable=no" breaks width / zoom level of viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723844/android-viewport-setting-user-scalable-no-breaks-width-zoom-level-of-viewpor)

Comment: Please don't disable zooming - it helps readers with impaired vision to expand your text for more comfortable reading.